# Three.js - How to debug object picking code?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Three.js on an app, currently I'm having issues with the object picking. Some objects are not getting intersected by the rays, but only on certain camera rotations. I'm trying to debug the code and to draw the ray.

I'm using this methods in my code(`canvas` is a namespace for the Three objects):

```
C.getXY = function(e) {
    var click = {};

    click.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    click.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    return click;
};


C.doPicking = function(e) {
    var picked = false;

    if (canvas.boundingBox !== null) {
        canvas.scene.remove(canvas.boundingBox);
    }

    var projector = new THREE.Projector(), click = C.getXY(e);
    var ray = projector.pickingRay(new THREE.Vector3(click.x, click.y, 0), canvas.camera);
    ray.linePrecision = 0.00000000000000001;
    ray.precision = 0.00000000000000001;
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(canvas.scene.children);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        var ids = [];

        while (i < intersects.length) {
            if (intersects[i].object.visible) {
                //Object is picked
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }
};
```

My question is...are other points to consider in the debuging process?

Comment: Why do you want such a small precision? It makes picking ray unreliable due to floating point Precision.

Comment: Geometry is very small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops...forgot to add `mesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();` before adding the meshes to the scene. Now the picking is working normally.